# convert two function together in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a google map on HTML page but underneath it has comment field box. The javascript file in an external file. When I put the Function together, the map doesn't work, but if I take out the Function of the comment field box, the map is works. What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="script/contact.js"></script>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script async defer
         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
         key=AIzaSyCu8zufWm3rgmPMoSafBG3vUwh8w2pb1JY&callback=initMap"></script>
      <br />
      <form method="post" name="myForm" 
         onsubmit="return formValidation();">
      <table class="formtable">
         <tr>
            <th> Full Name: </th>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="frstname" size="60"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Email: </th>
            <td><input name="email" id="emailid" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" size="60" required></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Comments: </th>
            <td><textarea name="commentbox" id="comment" cols="50" rows="3" required placeholder="Comments"></textarea></td>
            <br>
         </tr>
         <input type="hidden" name="sendto" id="sendto" value="myaddress@somewhere.com">
         <tr>
            <th> 
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send Form"> <input type="reset"></td>
            <br>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </table>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

And this is the external javascript

```
function initMap() {

    var shop = {
        lat: -28.120944,
        lng: 153.471851
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: shop
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: shop,
        map: map
    });
}

function formValidation() {
    if var value = document.getElementById('emailid').value
    if (value == "") {
        alert("nothing in email");
        return false;
    }

    var value = document.getElementById('comment').value
    if (value == "") {
        alert("nothing in comment");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors, for instance missing parentheses and syntax errors.

Comment: are you sure the external js is loaded ??

Comment: I'll make my hint clearer ... `if var value = document.getElementById...` is an error.

Comment: put the first if statement inside round brackets. Also, don't define a variable inside the if statement, remove the var. define the value variable on a line by its self.

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox you can right click on the document, view page source, and see all the HTML mistakes highlighted in red - there are a few more than the missing, closing </form> tag. Chrome doesn't appear to offer the service.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now.